# Переменная по имени в Java

Tags: java, android

В PHP есть такая вещь как:

```
$a = "name";
$$a = "Hello";
echo $name; // выводит "Hello"
```

Подскажите, как такое можно реализовать динамически в Java? Вообще интересует как такое сделать в Java, как на PHP в примере ниже:

```
$name = "track";
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
   $temp = $name . $i; // Получаем track1
   SendToFunction($$temp); //Передаем в функцию переменную $track1
}
```

Для чего вообще мне это нужно? Хочу вместо явного указания track1 в `track1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`
использовать нужную мне переменную, что бы не писать много кода, т.к. не все `trackX` мне придется передавать в функцию

Comment: Какой ужас. В java такими извращениями не занимаются.

Comment: В java нет ссылок на переменные. Всё ссылается на конкретные экземпляры объектов. Часто такой пхп-шный приём просто не нужен. Две, три, 100500 переменных могут одновременно ссылаться на один и тот же объект совершенно обычным способом. В других случаях всегда найдётся то или иное решение. На самом деле не ясно, что точно Вам надо, но можно хранить треки в масиве, в коллекции (цикл как бы намекает) или применить Map (как кто-то пишет в своём ответе)

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш комментарий. Нужно это для того, что бы не использовать switch case, а пройтись в цикле по всем imageView  и если там будут "пустые" просто их пропустить

Comment: возможно вам поможет рефлексия. Но это совсем крайний метод.

Answer (score 6):

можете в `Map` записать соответствие имени типа `Track1` переменым, и доставать нужные переменные по имени.
Конкретно использовать переменную по имени динамически нельзя, т. к. `Java` компилируется не динамически, как `PHP`

```
Map<String, Track> tracks = new HashMap<>();
tracks.put("Track1", new Track(<какие-то данные о треке>));
tracks.put("Track2", new Track(<какие-то данные о треке>));
tracks.put("Track3", new Track(<какие-то данные о треке>));

int i = 2; //надо передать Track2 в метод
Track track = tracks.get("Track" + i);
someMethod(track);
```

Писал на коленке, мог ошибиться в синтаксисе, но принцип такой.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Не могли бы подсказать как это реализовать конкретно на моем примере выше?

Comment: @pavel, Что? Что за рефлексия? Причем тут она вообще?

Comment: @pavel, ок, а вы уверены, что ваш комментарий относится к моему ответу, а не к вопросу автора?

Comment: @GosuUndeadGhost, JS тоже компилируется динамически. Еще раз повторю, в JAVA так не получится.